# Is it better practice to pass an object, set it in another class as void, or to return the object in java?

Tags: java, pojo

I understand java objects are referenced, so updating the model in a different class/method even when passed will update the original object.

But I am just wondering if it is better practice to pass it back, or just to update it as void in a different method?

Updating without passing back:

```
class MyModel () {
 private int myValue = 0;
 // getter setter
} 

class MyProcessor() {
 MyModel newModel = new MyModel();
 doSomething(newModel);
 newModel = //do more porcessing
}

public void doSomething(MyModel newModel) {
 newValue = //do some processing, and get a new value
 newModel.setMyValue(newValue);
}
```

OR

Updating and pass back:

```
class MyModel () {
 private int myValue = 0;
 // getter setter
}

class MyProcessor() {
 MyModel newModel = new MyModel();
 newModel = doSomething(newModel);
 newModel = //do more porcessing
}

public MyModel doSomething(MyModel newModel) {
 newValue = //do some processing, and get a new value
 newModel.setMyValue(newValue);
 return newModel;
}
```

If my understanding is correct it is exactly the same, but what would be the best practice?

Comment: This is largely opinion-based, but from an API design point of view, returning the object might give the impression that the method actually returns a copy of the object instead of operating on the original one. For that reason, the `void` version would be preferable. There are some exceptions to this rule, e.g. builder patterns or fluent APIs.

Comment: Another concept to consider is self documenting code.  If your method was called `updateMyModel`, then would that change the need for the input model to be returned?

Comment: I find it's more obvious to return the value in most cases.

Comment: if you're doing something with with newModel then you should had newModel.doSomething() hence doSomething() should me a member of Model

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen good point, i do prefer not returning the object as well as it does seem like a new copy is being passed aorund

Comment: @TheGoldy I am passing the model to a validator utility that is shared among other models, so in this case I don't think its suitable to put it in the model itself